# What happens if ground and neutral are swapped in a light switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, grounding, neutral

I’m replacing a light switch in an old house with lots of uncolored wiring. I removed the switch plate to find two black wires (connected to the switch) and a capped up white wire (see photo below).

Is that white wire ground or neutral? What’s the difference? What happens if I think it’s a neutral wire but it’s a ground instead? (For what it’s worth, I’m installing a wifi switch that requires a neutral.)

[image: switch]

Comment: An electrical expert will weigh in with an informed answer. But I don't see anything in that photo that looks like ground. Only neutral. Neutral is the wire that current returns to the panel on when a circuit is being used. Ground is for shunting unwanted voltage. Both are needed, but the latter may not be present in older wiring. Adding it requires new wire; don't try to use the neutral as an alternative to ground. Your wifi switch probably wants _both_ neutral and ground, and you should provide both. It's possible that metal box is grounded.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Helpful, thanks! Neutral is traditionally white, right?

Comment: Yes. I believe it's more than just tradition. There are rules governing wire colors, and neutral is required to be white or gray, if I recall correctly, and these colors are prohibited from being used in other applications unless some additional marking is used (i.e. colored electrical tape at the connection). I don't have the code memorized like some others here; I'm sure within the next 24-48 hours, you'll get an actual, informed answer to the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho To address your comment about whether the Wi-Fi switch needs both neutral and ground: the instructions say that it requires a neutral but ground seems to be optional. Does that make sense to you? Honestly though, the instructions look like they were translated from Chinese maybe, so I don’t exactly know if the translation is trustworthy.

Comment: There are at least two considerations: operational and safety. It's entirely possible that the switch _can operate successfully_ without a ground connection. But whether doing is safe, and especially whether doing so meets the electrical code requirement, I don't know. A regular (mechanical) switch typically _won't_ need a connection to ground. But once you have current passing through the switch back to neutral, it's possible that a ground connection would be needed for safety. Products may or may not provide accurate information with respect to legal requirements (i.e. code).

Comment: @PeterDuniho There does appear to be a ground but the OP would have to test it to be sure. The cable going into the box is flexible metal conduit which is probably grounded. you can see the red insulation barriers protecting the wires from the edge of the metal. That conduit connecting to the box would be an appropriate ground.

Comment: @JACK Interesting. Your eyes are better than mine. Where is that flexible metal conduit? Thanks!

Comment: @Sam It's coming in from the top. The paper wrapping  is a clue and so are the red insulating rings. Two separate runs.  If you have a meter, test from the hot black to the metal box and you should get 120V.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm checking with the manufacturer to see if the switch can operate safely without a ground. If so, and since we've determined that those white wires are neutral, I can just uncap the white neutral cluster and connect a neutral from the new switch to the cluster right? Thanks!

Comment: @JACK: _"cable going into the box is flexible metal conduit which is probably grounded"_ -- I did already mention [that the box might be the ground](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/204263/what-happens-if-ground-and-neutral-are-swapped-in-a-light-switch?noredirect=1#comment371551_204263).

Comment: To run the smart switch you will be fine. The hot black will go to the black screw on the switch. 2nd black from light goes to the red screw on the smart switch. Most smart switches comes with a jumper wire but if not cut a jumper to connect to the whites(common). Add the jumper to the 2 whites with a wire nut and attach jumper to silver screw on switch. Test before install switch back in box

Comment: Keep in mind that separate ground wires were not required until maybe 1960.  Judging from the paper wrapped around your wires they probably predate this.

Comment: On the color code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring#Colour_code

Answer (score 9):

You have no ground visible.  Hot is switched with Black in and out while Neutral is passed thru.

Comment: Ok. So just to be super clear here, that white wire is neutral? Is that what you’re saying? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can you explain the second half of your comment? “Couple of volts to ground…”? I understand electrical concepts, but I’m not good with the jargon! Ha!

Comment: _"couple volts"_ means that neutral and ground are not always at exactly the same voltage potential. There could be some small difference, resulting in "a couple of volts" potential when you compare the two (i.e. put a volt meter with one probe on ground and one on neutral)

Comment: So, can I uncap the white neutral cluster and connect a neutral from the new switch to this cluster? Thanks!

Comment: There does appear to be a ground but the OP would have to test it to be sure. The cable going into the box is flexible metal conduit which is probably grounded. you can see the red insulation barriers protecting the wires from the edge of the metal. That conduit connecting to the box would be an appropriate ground.

Comment: Ok if that rusty screw on top has external lug with a ground wire not seen, yes. You can also see a couple insulation nicks on the black wires from squeezing the wires in against the box sharp edges. Yet nothing suggests either black or white neutral wires are improper. He only needs to determine which wire is unswitched to use.

Comment: @Sam An important thing to understand about the capped neutral wires is that they don’t all lead to the same place.  There is a good chance one of them leads back to the breaker and the other leads to the light.  They MUST remain connected.  Do not simply remove one of the white wires from the wire nut and screw it into your new switch.  You need to ADD a short white wire (called a jumper) to the nut and connect THAT to the switch.  That way the light’s neutral and the switch’s neutral have a path back to the breaker.

Comment: @PeterDuniho There should *NOT* be a couple of volts between neutral and ground.  With 50A flowing through a 1000ft of AWG 14 wire you would expect a *couple of volts* difference.  You should never have 1000ft runs of wire in a house and 14AWG wire should never have 50A flowing through it.  If you're seeing a couple of volts between neutral and ground then the neutral line almost certainly has damage or a bad splice somewhere between you and the panel.  Either that or your meter is broken.

Comment: @J...  not all homes are well earth bonded to neutral on site so the connection is at the DT, which can be that for away for a 200A service

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I've never seen a utility supply a ground conductor.

Comment: @J... The depth and resistance of earth bonding can be lower at the DT than house, if residential ground rod is dry and poor R.  This is what I meant. https://inspectapedia.com/electric/0505s.jpg

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The quality of the ground rod has absolutely no effect on the contact resistance of the equipotential bond.  If the home is not well bonded in the panel that's a defect and it needs to be corrected. (ie: you should NOT have a **couple of** volts between neutral and ground).

Comment: My understanding is NA 10% voltage regulation is allotted 50/50 between generation and distribution incl. residence which I have seen a couple volts on N with a 70’s built house with underground water pipes grounded but dry in winter.  Therefore I assumed in house line drop and neutral rise was about 2%. But I’ll test this mid80’s built home.  However swapping gnd and neutral will only upset GFCI’s that operate on low diff current between line and neutral. If at breaker, that might trip if reversed down stream.

Comment: I measured zero point one Volts on range Neutral. Good. 0.0 in garage. No change in Neutral with full load on oven and stove, but that is 240 split phase for oven. Line dropped from 120.1 to 117.5 on range outlet on full load, so 2% on Line, 0% on N. confirmed your comment. TY. Which reminds me the previous house with 2 V on Neutral had ground and neutral reversed in the attic with 16 pot lights added by some rookie for previous owner, which I fixed.  I also deleted my incorrect comment.  That’s only when N-G are reversed under load.

Answer (score 9):

Green, yellow-green, or bare are supposed to be safety ground only.

In North America, neutral is required to be carried on white or gray wires.

If neutral is not needed in a cable, the white can be re-tasked to be a hot wire. Code now requires such white wires be marked with tape, but most installers do not.

Hots are every other color.

You have 2 white wires in that cluster. Even though they're not attached to the switch, they're equally important.  **Generally a cluster of all whites are neutral**.

Rarely, you'll see 1 white in a cluster of hots; that's the "cable exception" I mentioned above.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So, it’s likely those capped white wires are neutral and just spit and capped in case they’re ever needed… right?

Comment: @sam no, they're being used right now!  Current flows in loops. They are the other half of the loop.

Comment: But can I uncap them and connect a neutral from the new switch to this cluster? Thanks!

Comment: and in this case the ground appears to be flexible metal conduit.

Comment: @Sam -- as long as all the existing neutrals are still connected together at the end of the day, yes, you can add the switch's neutral to the neutral bundle

Comment: Ground was yellow-green even in late USSR and friends.

Comment: I'd prefer you to claim "Ground is *supposed to be* green..." and "Neutral *is supposed to be* white". Making bold claims about what wire colors definitely will be what, on the internet, when you haven't inspected the particular installation to see if the previous resident, armed with even less knowledge than the current resident has, did to the wiring "to get X Y Z to work" **could have fatal consequences**

Comment: @CaiusJard Conceded. However the earlier edit never said  "(colors) are always ground", ha ha, right... it said "Ground is always (colors)".  The latter was informed by my experience here; note my rep.

Comment: "Green, yellow-green, or bare are supposed to be safety ground only. *That is true worldwide*." In lots of Dutch homes green is phase and ground is grey or white, and as long as no significant new work is done on the installation this is up to code.

Answer (score 8):

To answer your original question, if ground and neutral are swapped, when the light is energized (on) you will have electrified your entire house ground as the return path to the main panel.  This is bad and dangerous.  The good news is, everything looks normal in the box as mentioned previously, the neutral feed is nutted to the lamps neutral and the hots (blacks) are switched at the switch.  There is no ground unless it is achieved though emt metal conduit.  If this is an old box pre 1970 it it possible there was no ground installed.  Why do you think the neutal and grounds may be swaped?

Comment: No, I don’t think they’ve been switched… just a bit new at this. So, can I uncap the white neutral cluster and connect a neutral from the new switch to this cluster? Thanks!

Comment: There does appear to be a ground but the OP would have to test it to be sure. The cable going into the box is flexible metal conduit which is probably grounded. you can see the red insulation barriers protecting the wires from the edge of the metal. That conduit connecting to the box would be an appropriate ground.

Comment: Older switches didnt need the neutral so it just passed on into the light through a wire nut pigtail.  The new smart switches use the neutral for their own power (so there will be three wires under the pigtail) .  This is why newer code requires the neutrals at the switch boxes even though it didnt used to be used there.

Comment: So, just to be clear, I can uncap the white neutral cluster and connect the neutral from the new switch to this cluster? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Yes. The three white wires will be:  one from the panel circuit wiring, one to the fixture light, and the new one to the smart switch.

Answer (score 0):

The black wires are your "hot" or power wires. The white are your neutrals and your ground is green, bare copper or the box if  ground is present.